# wordpress custom theme using php

Tags: php, wordpress

I need a help in WordPress custom theme using PHP development, I was created language dropdown with images and in configure with Gtranslator Plugin, it`s work properly but when I select other language flag can't change in Dropdown.
my Code is given below:

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="JavaScript:void(0)" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><img class="lang_icon" src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri();?>/images/usaicon.png"> 
        <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown_language">
        <li><a onclick="doGTranslate('en|en')" href="JavaScript:void(0)">
            <img class="lang_icon" src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri();?>/images/usaicon.png">
            </a>
        </li>
        <li id="cn"><a onclick="doGTranslate('en|zh-CN')" href="JavaScript:void(0)">
                    <img class="lang_icon" src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri();?>/images/chinaicon.png">
                    </a>
        </li>
        <li><a onclick="doGTranslate('en|es')" href="JavaScript:void(0)">
            <img class="lang_icon" src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri();?>/images/mexiconicon.png">
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

[image]

Comment: where is the code?

Comment: you're trying this with bootstrap drop-down menu.
and it will not work because when page will refreshed value will be refreshed.

you have to modify the doGTranslate() function and add active class for the current language on page load.